# Flink Kafka program in scala giving timeout error org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am writing a Flink Kafka integration program as below but getting timeout error for kafka  :

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.{FlinkKafkaConsumer010, 
FlinkKafkaProducer010}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import java.util.Properties

object StreamKafkaProducer {

def main(args: Array[String]) {
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
properties.setProperty("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")


val stream: DataStream[String] =env.fromElements(
  ("Adam"),
  ("Sarah"))

val kafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer010[String](
  "localhost:9092",
  "output",
  new SimpleStringSchema
)
// write data into Kafka
stream.addSink(kafkaProducer)

env.execute("Flink kafka integration  ")
}
}
```

From terminal I can see kafka and zookeeper are running but when I run above program from Intellij it is showing this error :

```
C:\Users\amdass\workspace\flink-project-master>sbt run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; 
support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\amdass\workspace\flink-
project-master\project
[info] Set current project to Flink Project (in build 
file:/C:/Users/amdass/workspace/flink-project-master/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\amdass\workspace\flink-project-
master\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[info] Running org.example.StreamKafkaProducer
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further 
details.
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka://flink/user/jobmanager_1#-563113020] 
with leader session id 5a637740-5c73-4f69-a19e-c8ef7141efa1.
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Job execution switched to status RUNNING.
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Source: Collection Source(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Sink: Unnamed(1/4) switched to SCHEDULED
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Sink: Unnamed(2/4) switched to SCHEDULED
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Sink: Unnamed(3/4) switched to SCHEDULED
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Sink: Unnamed(4/4) switched to SCHEDULED
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Source: Collection Source(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Sink: Unnamed(1/4) switched to DEPLOYING
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Sink: Unnamed(2/4) switched to DEPLOYING
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Sink: Unnamed(3/4) switched to DEPLOYING
12/15/2017 14:41:49     Sink: Unnamed(4/4) switched to DEPLOYING
12/15/2017 14:41:50     Source: Collection Source(1/1) switched to RUNNING
12/15/2017 14:41:50     Sink: Unnamed(2/4) switched to RUNNING
12/15/2017 14:41:50     Sink: Unnamed(4/4) switched to RUNNING
12/15/2017 14:41:50     Sink: Unnamed(3/4) switched to RUNNING
12/15/2017 14:41:50     Sink: Unnamed(1/4) switched to RUNNING
12/15/2017 14:41:50     Source: Collection Source(1/1) switched to FINISHED
12/15/2017 14:41:50     Sink: Unnamed(3/4) switched to FINISHED
12/15/2017 14:41:50     Sink: Unnamed(4/4) switched to FINISHED
12/15/2017 14:42:50     Sink: Unnamed(1/4) switched to FAILED
<b>  org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata 
after 60000 ms. </b>

12/15/2017 14:42:50     Sink: Unnamed(2/4) switched to FAILED
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata 
after 60000 ms.

12/15/2017 14:42:50     Job execution switched to status FAILING.
```

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
12/15/2017 14:42:50     Job execution switched to status FAILED.
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:933)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:876)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$6.apply(JobManager.scala:876)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at

scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107
    )
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update 
    metadata after 60000 ms.
    [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:run for the full output.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
    [error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
    [error] Total time: 75 s, completed Dec 15, 2017 2:42:51 PM

Answer (score 0):

Please check and make sure your Kafka Server is running.
This error is generally when your Flink program is unable to connect to Kafka server.
Flink automatically tries to connect to Kafka server with some threshold time.Once this threshold is reached and still Flink is not able to make a connection with Kafka then it will throw this **org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException**

Please check your Kafka server details, Kafka Topic, and validate if your Kafka server is running.